# Creation of random matrix with 10%,..,90% zeros

Tags: matrix, octave

I am trying to create a matrix with entrys between -1 and 1 and 10%,20%,...,90% zeros in matlab. What I have so far is

```
numRows = 100;                        % Number of Rows
numCols = 2*numRows;                  % Number of Columns
percentageZeros = 0.1 : 0.1 : 0.9;    % Percentage of Zeros (options)


for currPercentageZeros = percentageZeros

  do 
    A = zeros(numRows, numCols);   % Initialize matrix

    for row = 1:numRows
      for col = 1:numCols
        rnd = rand;
        if rnd > currPercentageZeros
          A(row, col) = 2*rand-1;
        endif  
      endfor
    endfor
  until (rank(A) == numRows)
```

but this not really accurate. Does anyone know a better solution?

Comment: `do`, `until` and `endfor` are not MATLAB. Either post MATLAB code, or tag Octave instead of MATLAB.

Comment: Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718200/random-numbers-using-rand-in-matlab) show how to generate a fixed number of zeros randomly. You need to add a bit to that to fill the other elements with random values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the remainder of the array to be uniformly distributed between -1 and 1

```matlab
numRows = 100;
numCols = 2*numRows;
percentageZeros = 0.1 : 0.1 : 0.9;

for i = 1:length(percentageZeros)
  r = rand(numRows, numCols); % create an array of random floats between 0 and 1
  A = 2 * rand(numRows, numCols) - 1; % create your output array between -1 and 1
  A(r <= percentageZeros(i)) = 0; % use r to decide which elements to remove from A
end
```

Comment: Here you don’t get the exact number of zeros, but each pixel has the desired chance of being zero.